# OpenFL - can someone explain __combinedVisible property of flash.display.Bitmap

Tags: html, haxe, openfl

Im using a Bitmap for a button in OpenFL. What im seeing when I set `myBitmap.visible = true` is that the bitmap does not become visible.

It seems I need to call `myBitmap.__CombinedVisible = true` as well for it to be drawn. I can't find any documentation for this property on how to use it properly.

I'm also noticing the first time I switch between 2 bitmaps that the bitmap made visible does not appear right away, but the one made invisible disappears right away. Any time after that it behaves properly and the switch happens instantly.

Could this have something to do with `__CombinedVisible`?

You can see the bitmap switching code below inside of my button.

```
private function update() : Void {
    if( state == ButtonState.OVER ){
        this.over.visible = this.over.__combinedVisible = true;
        this.up.visible = this.down.visible = false;
    }else if( state == ButtonState.UP ){
        this.up.visible = this.up.__combinedVisible = true;
        this.down.visible = this.over.visible = false;
    } else if( state == ButtonState.DOWN ){
        this.down.visible = this.down.__combinedVisible = true;
        this.up.visible = this.over.visible = false;
    }else if( state == ButtonState.CLICK ) {
        this.up.visible = this.up.__combinedVisible = true;
        this.over.visible = this.down.visible = false;
        this.enabled = false;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("CLICK")); 
    }
}
```

So after a bunch of testing I'v narrowed it down to this: If I set `visible` to false prior to assigning the `BitmapData` this `__combinedVisible` member seems to need to be used. If I do it right after setting the `BitmapData` it still needs this.

If I let the bitmap draw for 1 frame then set `visible` to `false`. `visible = true` works after this happens and I can now see the bitmap.

But if it doesn't draw once then `visible = true` does not show the bitmap.

Can I not create an empty bitmap this way and assign the `BitmapData` later? It works on the up state as I never set `visible = false` prior to it being drawn the first time.

Comment: OpenFL does not have a `__combinedVisible` property, not even privately. Can you post to http://community.openfl.org with information about what version you are using?

Comment: ITs an older version we are stuck on. I havent seen anything in documentation about it but the property is there in the console.
Version = 1.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after tons of testing and trying to get this to work it just won't.

There is a bug here where if `visible` is set to `false` before drawing the bitmap to the canvas it won't draw it until `__combinedVisible` is set to `true`. This always causes a flash when drawing the bitmap for the first time as well, so its not feasible to use.

I went and used `alpha` instead of `visible`. This works properly and as expected.

If someone can get this working with `visible` I will accept that answer.

```
private function update() : Void {
    if( state == ButtonState.OVER ){
        this.over.alpha = 1;
        this.up.alpha = this.down.alpha  = 0;
    }else if( state == ButtonState.UP ){
        this.up.alpha = 1;
        this.down.alpha = this.over.alpha = 0;
    } else if( state == ButtonState.DOWN ){
        this.down.alpha = 1;
        this.up.alpha = this.over.alpha = 0;
    }else if( state == ButtonState.CLICK ) {
        this.up.alpha = 1;
        this.over.alpha = this.down.alpha = 0;
        this.enabled = false;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("CLICK"));
    }
}
```